PowerShell, change PowerShell/CMD Console Font and Layout in Windows 10 version 2
I have asked this question before Change PowerShell Console Font and Layout in Windows 10, but there was no definitive answer on the previous one (using a different approach) and my new question tries to address this by a different approach.
I realised that the font, buffer, layout information is stored within the .lnk file for a console in Windows, i.e. .lnk's for a PowerShell or CMD console are very different from a web link pointing at a URL, or a shortcut pointing to a file/folder in the filesystem, although all three types share the .lnk extension.
It then occurred to me that I can do the following:

Drag the PowerShell icon from the Start menu onto the desktop, and call it PowerShell.lnk
Then create a duplicate of that, calling it PowerShell20.lnk
Open up the Properties of PowerShell20.lnk and change it to font size 20 and close Properties.

Now, all I need to do is do a bit-comparison of the two .lnk files to see exactly what has changed, and save that information to a 2nd PowerShell script that I can use to apply this change to the first .lnk, and in this way, I can then apply these changes to any console .lnk. I could then use that modifier script on any new Windows 10 or 11 to adjust properties exactly as I want, all from PowerShell.
The following almost does all of this, creating the modifier script, which does apply the changes to PowerShell.lnk but it doesn't quite work and the final PowerShell.lnk shortcut is broken. How can we use the bit-differences found between two console shortcuts to be able to build a generic script that can alter a console shortcuts Font (or other properties) without breaking the shortcut?
# Paths to the shortcut files
$originalShortcutPath = "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\PowerShell.lnk"
$modifiedShortcutPath = "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\PowerShell20.lnk"
$fixScriptPath = "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\FixPowerShell.ps1"

# Read shortcut files as binary data
$originalBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($originalShortcutPath)
$modifiedBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($modifiedShortcutPath)

# Find differing bits and generate fix script
$differences = @()
$fixScriptContent = @()
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $originalBytes.Length; $i++) {
    $originalByte = $originalBytes[$i]
    $modifiedByte = $modifiedBytes[$i]
    for ($j = 0; $j -lt 8; $j++) {
        $originalBit = ($originalByte -band ([math]::Pow(2, $j))) -shr $j
        $modifiedBit = ($modifiedByte -band ([math]::Pow(2, $j))) -shr $j
        if ($originalBit -ne $modifiedBit) {
            $bitIndex = $i * 8 + $j
            $differences += "Bit $bitIndex is different, has value: $modifiedBit"
            $fixScriptContent += "Set-Content -Path '$originalShortcutPath' -Value ([System.BitConverter]::ToString([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32(@(Get-Content -Path '$originalShortcutPath' -Encoding Byte), 0) -bxor (1 -shl $bitIndex)), 0) -Encoding Byte -NoNewline"
        }
    }
}

# Write fix script
$fixScriptContent | Out-File -FilePath $fixScriptPath -Encoding ASCII

if ($differences.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No differences found between the two files."
} else {
    Write-Host "Listing every bit that is different in $($modifiedShortcutPath):"
    $differences
    Write-Host "Fix script generated at $fixScriptPath"
}


You have an issue with your algo. In your comparaison you are assuming the size of the original version is greater or equal than your modified version. Your for loop may stop before reaching the end of the modifiedBytes array if the modifed file is bigger.

Thanks, I see what you mean. Possibly my approach is unworkable? I don't know enough about the structure of shortcuts to know I guess.

Did the following:

I found the "Windows PowerShell.lnk" file
Made a copy
Edited the copy's font size to equal 20
Made a copy of the copy
Edited the copy of a copy's font size to equal 24
Used FC.EXE /B on the copy and the copy of a copy

Found several changes, but this line
00000815: 14 18  matches what I expected as 0x14=20 and 0x18=24.


Knowing the original font size is 14 or 0x0E, and now knowing approximant location into the file to expect the font size to be located, used HxD to search for 0E and found it at position 7F1.

This brings me to the following PowerShell script:
$filePath = "$PSScriptRoot\CustomPowerShell.lnk"
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($filePath)

$address = 0x7F1
$newValue = 20
if($bytes[$address] = 14) {
   $bytes[$address] = 20
   [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($filePath, $bytes)
}

This script modifies the file contents of the file defined in $filePath by first checking if the value at 0x7F1 matches the expected value of 14, and if so, it then replaces that value with 20 and writes the new file contents back to the drive.
This is great as long as windows never changes the content of this shortcut file.  But what if Windows does provide an altered version in the future?
In further examining of the file, I discovered that value 14 (0x0E) was found in only one place, the font size.
It seems unlikely that future versions of Windows will change this font size to something else, and unlikely a future version of the shortcut file will contain the value 0x0E (14) for some reason other than the font size - that is where this version of the script comes in:
$filePath = "$PSScriptRoot\CustomPowerShell.lnk"
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($filePath)

0x771..0x871 | & {
   begin {
      $ChangeCount = 0
   }
   process{
      if($bytes[$_] -eq 14) {
         $bytes[$_] = 20
         $ChangeCount++
      }
   }
   end {
      if ($ChangeCount -eq 1) {
         [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($filePath, $bytes)
      }
      else {
         Write-Host "ERROR: Found $ChangeCount instances of the value 14, where only 1 was expected.  File not altered."
      }
   }
}

This second version assumes the following:

The original font size will always be 14.
It will always be found someplace from position 0x771 to 0x871.
No other value in the range 0x771 to 0x871 will be equal to 14.

This second script will modify the shortcut file ONLY if it finds one instance of the value 0x0E (14) in the positions from 0x771 to 0x871. If it finds more than one value 0x0E (14), or fails to find the value, it then reports the failure and leaves the file unchanged.

I don't think these positions will ever change, this .lnk type has been around maybe since Windows XP or older, maybe 20+ years, but they just never exposed a method to modify it programmatically via properties (as with TargetPath etc for the other .lnk types). And this will almost certainly not change now as Microsoft have also made it fairly clear that the Terminal application is the future (having bundled it into Windows 11) but I often prefer the simple uni-purpose / non-tabbed console. Really appreciate this, I've been looking for such a method for some years without success.

@YorSubs, you are welcome.  The answer is kind of hack-ish and I would much prefer to edit font size property by some other means.  But, If this works for now, then great.  I suspect there is a way to do it in c++, but I would need a code example, docs or something to do it.

After a few hours of experimentation, it looks like I was a little over-enthusiastic earlier. While this does work for the case where we alter a known shortcut, and indeed, I think I was right in saying that the console .lnk is a fixed standard of 20+ years, sadly, these .lnk types vary in length greatly (from as small as 800 bytes up to 4k in size), but this Microsoft "standard" is unpublished and vague. Your technique does identify localised changes, so is very useful for specific value changes, but unfortunately the location of that value does seem to change as you feared initially...

How to modify the font size in a .lnk file using PowerShell
The font size, and other properties, in a .lnk file can be edited by searching through its internal structures for the structure that has the desired property as a member.  In the case of changing the font size, the desired structure is CONSOLE_PROPS, and the desired member is "The two most significant bytes" of FontSize, which contain the font height.
Load the Shortcut File: Start by loading the .lnk file into a byte array. This allows us to edit the file in memory.
$lnkPath = "$PSScriptRoot\CustomPowerShell.lnk"
$lnkContent = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($lnkPath)

Identify Structures: Determine which structures are present, and will need to be navigated, in the file by reading the link flags. Also, move $pointer past the first, and only mandatory structure, ShellLinkHeader.
$pointer = [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($lnkContent, 0x0)
$linkFlags = [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($lnkContent, 0x0014)

Navigate Identified Structures: Increment $pointer, moving past each existing structure, until the arriving at the extra data section of the .lnk file.
if ($linkFlags -band 0x00000001) { $pointer += 2 + [BitConverter]::ToUInt16($lnkContent, $pointer) }     #  HasLinkTargetIDList
if ($linkFlags -band 0x00000002) { $pointer += [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($lnkContent, $pointer) }         #  HasLinkInfo
if ($linkFlags -band 0x00000004) { $pointer += 2 + 2 * [BitConverter]::ToUInt16($lnkContent, $pointer) } #  HasName
if ($linkFlags -band 0x00000008) { $pointer += 2 + 2 * [BitConverter]::ToUInt16($lnkContent, $pointer) } #  HasRelativePath
if ($linkFlags -band 0x00000010) { $pointer += 2 + 2 * [BitConverter]::ToUInt16($lnkContent, $pointer) } #  HasWorkingDir
if ($linkFlags -band 0x00000020) { $pointer += 2 + 2 * [BitConverter]::ToUInt16($lnkContent, $pointer) } #  HasArguments
if ($linkFlags -band 0x00000040) { $pointer += 2 + 2 * [BitConverter]::ToUInt16($lnkContent, $pointer) } #  HasIconLocation
if ($linkFlags -band 0x00000200) { $pointer += [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($lnkContent, $pointer) }         #  HasExpString
if ($linkFlags -band 0x00001000) { $pointer += [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($lnkContent, $pointer) }         #  HasDarwinID
if ($linkFlags -band 0x00004000) { $pointer += [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($lnkContent, $pointer) }         #  HasExpIcon

Search Extra Data for the Desired Structure: Font size is stored in the CONSOLE_PROPS structure that is defined as a ConsoleDataBlock, and has the block signature 0xA0000002.  Each structure is checked for matching signature, and if matching, the font height is changed to 24.
The search is finished when the loop reads a block size less than 4 bytes. This last read is actually reading a TerminalBlock, a 4 byte unsigned int, that typically will have the value 0x00000000, but the docs explicitly state "This value MUST be less than 0x00000004".
while ( ( $blockSize = [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($lnkContent, $pointer) ) -ge 0x00000004) {
   $blockSignature = [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($lnkContent, ($pointer + 4))
   if ( $blockSignature -eq [uint32]'0xA0000002') {   #  CONSOLE_PROPS / ConsoleDataBlock
      $posFontHeight = $pointer + 34
      $NewFontHeight = 24
      ([BitConverter]::GetBytes([UInt16]$NewFontHeight)).CopyTo($lnkContent, $posFontHeight)
   }
   $pointer += $blockSize
}

Write Changes to File: After modifying the font height, save the changes back to the file. Optionally, modify this part to save to a new file instead.
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($lnkPath, $lnkContent)

The above code edits only the font height. You can similarly modify other properties in any structure, not just CONSOLE_PROPS, by navigating to the correct structure, and then navigating to the desired property in that structure.

This looks incredible (and it seems that you found the actual Microsoft specification for this .lnk type!). Going to set aside some time today to try and understand your amazing work here.

@YorSubs, my biggest concern is that the moving past the optional structures may have an incorrect $pointer += ... statement.  The shortcut I was working with only had HasLinkTargetIDList, HasLinkInfo. HasRelativePath. and HasWorkingDir in the link flags.  So I'm assuming HasName, HasArguments, and HasIconLocation are identical to HasRelativePath and HasWorkingDir.  Also assuming that HasExpString, HasDarwinID, and HasExpIcon are identical to HasLinkInfo

@YorSubs, no promises that I will get around to doing this, but I would like to test all the shortcuts on my computer looking for examples of each link flag being used.  Then testing some of those examples to verify that each $pointer += ... is correctly skipping that structure and the Extra Data section is successfully found.

@YorSubs, just remembered another concern.  The strings are Unicode, but if IsUnicode flag is not set set, they may be ASCII.  Also, I'm thinking Unicode can be sometimes be 4 bytes instead of 2 bytes per character.  This leaves me uncertain if the 2 byte length at the front of strings can be simply multiplied by 2, or do you actually need to read and count each char in the sting, detecting when the char is 4 bytes or just 2 bytes (Been a long time since I read about Unicode).  This is a concern for reading HasName, HasRelativePath, HasWorkingDir, HasArguments, and HasIconLocation
